# Confusion about git status and commits on different branches

Tags: git

I was on the master branch and created a new branch and moved to it:

```
git branch br2
git checkout br2
```

I then made 2 commits on br2

I moved back to master

```
git checkout master
```

I did some work and made 3 commits

Now I want to push these 3 commits to origin/master
First I do :

```
git status.
```

git status says :

On branch master.  Your branch is ahead of orgin/master by 5 commits.

That seems odd.  I only did 3 commits on the master branch.

So I run:

```
git log origin/master..HEAD
```

It shows 5 commits including the ones I did on the br2.  In the listing of the commits, there is no indication of what branch they are associated with.

I'm a little confused.   I want to push just those 3 commits I did on master, but I'm fearing that the 2 I did on br2 are going to be included.

Is there a better way for me to see what commits on the current (in this case master) branch are going to be pushed?

I have no plans to create a remote br2 branch.  At some point I thought I'd merge br2 into master and then do a push so that all the br2 commits would go into the remote master at that time.   Am I understanding this right?

Comment: `git status` won't "list" commits, it shows changes in the working directory. Please include actual commands and actual output, otherwise we can't really help.

Comment: I forgot to put the git log command in there which lists the commits.

Comment: See the linked duplicate, `git push --dry-run` is what you're after